# On touch listener and update other row item in recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi i have recyclerView row item consists of a play Button(Which change to stop and Play as toggle) and a play seek bar and TextView.

The each row plays different audios .

When i click on play button of respective row i am able to stop the other row audio ..
Addressing to the problem .. 
When i am playing a audio of a respective row, the button of earlier row has to stow a play symbol (in the sense it has to change the state ) please help me how to update the other rows of recyclerView when the other item is clicked

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int i) {

    if (holder.viewType == ROW_TYPE){
       // holder.play_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button);

        if(i == selected_item){

        }
        else {
           // holder.play_button.setImageResource();
        }
        JSONObject obj;
        String mp3_url = null, caption = null, thumbnail_url = null;

        try {
            obj = voicesArray.getJSONObject(i);
            mp3_url = obj.getString("mp3_url");
            caption = obj.getString("caption");
            thumbnail_url = obj.getString("thumbnail_url");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        holder.list_text.setText(caption);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(thumbnail_url, holder.list_image);


        final String finalMp3_url = mp3_url;
        holder.play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                selected_item = i;
               int ii = holder.getOldPosition();
               // holder.play_button.setImageResource();

              //  updateItem(ii);

                if(player != null){

                    player.reset();
                    holder.play_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button);
                    myAudioPlay(holder, finalMp3_url);
                }

                else {

                    myAudioPlay(holder,finalMp3_url);
                    /*if (player == null) {
                        player = new MediaPlayer();
                        playAudiFile(finalMp3_url);
                        holder.play_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_button);

                    } else if (player.isPlaying()) {
                        holder.play_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button);

                        player.stop();

                        Log.d("player", "" + player);
                        player.reset();
                    } else {
                        holder.play_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_button);
                        playAudiFile(finalMp3_url);
                    }*/
                }






            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the purpose of a recyclerView is to recycle the views to minimize memory usage required for rendering view so setting an image in the view is not an apt solution,Their are many solutions for your problem the One i would pick(Pseudo code) is given below

### Step 1. Create a Boolean value in your model class

```
bool isPlay=true;
```

### Step 2. When you are playing an audio loop through your Model for the recycler adapter and set the value for `isPlay` accourdingly

```
for(object obj in listOfModels)
 if(obj.Id!=idOfthePlayingView)
        obj.isPlay=false;
```

Then notify your adapter

```
yourRecyclerAdapterObject.notifyDatasetChanged()
```